# How can I create a environment in anaconda when I'm getting UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict: …?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, opencv, computer-vision, anaconda

I'm a newbie trying to explore OpenCV, I had to create a virtual environment in anaconda with the dependencies from the .yml file, However the numpy dependency seems to cause some trouble while setting up the environment.

The environment is being created with the help of a .yml file and is being created in the desktop(Writable).

how do I overcome this error?

my .yml file:

```
name: python-cvcourse
channels:
  - michael_wild
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - absl-py=0.4.1=py36_0
  - appdirs=1.4.3=py36h28b3542_0
  - asn1crypto=0.24.0=py36_0
  - astor=0.7.1=py36_0
  - attrs=18.2.0=py36h28b3542_0
  - automat=0.7.0=py36_0
  - backcall=0.1.0=py36_0
  - blas=1.0=mkl
  - bleach=2.1.4=py36_0
  - ca-certificates=2018.03.07=0
  - certifi=2018.10.15=py36_0
  - cffi=1.11.5=py36h74b6da3_1
  - colorama=0.3.9=py36h029ae33_0
  - constantly=15.1.0=py36h28b3542_0
  - cryptography=2.3.1=py36h74b6da3_0
  - cudatoolkit=9.0=1
  - cudnn=7.1.4=cuda9.0_0
  - cycler=0.10.0=py36h009560c_0
  - decorator=4.3.0=py36_0
  - entrypoints=0.2.3=py36_2
  - freetype=2.9.1=ha9979f8_1
  - gast=0.2.0=py36_0
  - grpcio=1.12.1=py36h1a1b453_0
  - h5py=2.8.0=py36hf7173ca_2
  - hdf5=1.8.20=hac2f561_1
  - html5lib=1.0.1=py36_0
  - hyperlink=18.0.0=py36_0
  - icc_rt=2017.0.4=h97af966_0
  - icu=58.2=ha66f8fd_1
  - idna=2.7=py36_0
  - incremental=17.5.0=py36_0
  - intel-openmp=2019.0=118
  - ipykernel=4.9.0=py36_0
  - ipython=6.5.0=py36_0
  - ipython_genutils=0.2.0=py36h3c5d0ee_0
  - ipywidgets=7.4.1=py36_0
  - jedi=0.12.1=py36_0
  - jinja2=2.10=py36_0
  - jpeg=9b=hb83a4c4_2
  - jsonschema=2.6.0=py36h7636477_0
  - jupyter=1.0.0=py36_6
  - jupyter_client=5.2.3=py36_0
  - jupyter_console=5.2.0=py36_1
  - jupyter_core=4.4.0=py36_0
  - jupyterlab=0.34.9=py36_0
  - jupyterlab_launcher=0.13.1=py36_0
  - keras=2.2.2=0
  - keras-applications=1.0.4=py36_1
  - keras-base=2.2.2=py36_0
  - keras-preprocessing=1.0.2=py36_1
  - kiwisolver=1.0.1=py36h6538335_0
  - libopencv=3.4.2=h20b85fd_0
  - libpng=1.6.34=h79bbb47_0
  - libprotobuf=3.6.0=h1a1b453_0
  - libsodium=1.0.16=h9d3ae62_0
  - libtiff=4.0.9=h36446d0_2
  - m2w64-gcc-libgfortran=5.3.0=6
  - m2w64-gcc-libs=5.3.0=7
  - m2w64-gcc-libs-core=5.3.0=7
  - m2w64-gmp=6.1.0=2
  - m2w64-libwinpthread-git=5.0.0.4634.697f757=2
  - markdown=2.6.11=py36_0
  - markupsafe=1.0=py36hfa6e2cd_1
  - matplotlib=2.2.3=py36hd159220_0
  - mistune=0.8.3=py36hfa6e2cd_1
  - mkl=2019.0=118
  - mkl_fft=1.0.4=py36h1e22a9b_1
  - mkl_random=1.0.1=py36h77b88f5_1
  - msys2-conda-epoch=20160418=1
  - nbconvert=5.3.1=py36_0
  - nbformat=4.4.0=py36h3a5bc1b_0
  - notebook=5.6.0=py36_0
  - numpy=1.15.1=py36ha559c80_0
  - numpy-base=1.15.1=py36h8128ebf_0
  - olefile=0.46=py36_0
  - opencv=3.4.2=py36h40b0b35_0
  - openssl=1.0.2p=hfa6e2cd_0
  - pandoc=2.2.3.2=0
  - pandocfilters=1.4.2=py36_1
  - parso=0.3.1=py36_0
  - pickleshare=0.7.4=py36h9de030f_0
  - pillow=5.2.0=py36h08bbbbd_0
  - pip=10.0.1=py36_0
  - prometheus_client=0.3.1=py36h28b3542_0
  - prompt_toolkit=1.0.15=py36h60b8f86_0
  - protobuf=3.6.0=py36he025d50_0
  - py-opencv=3.4.2=py36hc319ecb_0
  - pyasn1=0.4.4=py36h28b3542_0
  - pyasn1-modules=0.2.2=py36_0
  - pycparser=2.18=py36_1
  - pygments=2.2.0=py36hb010967_0
  - pyopenssl=18.0.0=py36_0
  - pyparsing=2.2.0=py36_1
  - pyqt=5.9.2=py36ha878b3d_0
  - python=3.6.6=hea74fb7_0
  - python-dateutil=2.7.3=py36_0
  - pytz=2018.5=py36_0
  - pywin32=223=py36hfa6e2cd_1
  - pywinpty=0.5.4=py36_0
  - pyyaml=3.13=py36hfa6e2cd_0
  - pyzmq=17.1.2=py36hfa6e2cd_0
  - qt=5.9.6=vc14h62aca36_0
  - qtconsole=4.4.1=py36_0
  - scikit-learn=0.19.1=py36hae9bb9f_0
  - scipy=1.1.0=py36h4f6bf74_1
  - send2trash=1.5.0=py36_0
  - service_identity=17.0.0=py36h28b3542_0
  - setuptools=40.2.0=py36_0
  - simplegeneric=0.8.1=py36_2
  - sip=4.19.8
  - six=1.11.0=py36_1
  - sqlite=3.24.0=h7602738_0
  - tensorflow=1.10.0
  - termcolor=1.1.0=py36_1
  - terminado=0.8.1=py36_1
  - testpath=0.3.1=py36h2698cfe_0
  - tk=8.6.8=hfa6e2cd_0
  - tornado=5.1=py36hfa6e2cd_0
  - traitlets=4.3.2=py36h096827d_0
  - twisted=18.7.0=py36hfa6e2cd_1
  - vc=14=h0510ff6_3
  - vs2015_runtime=14.0.25123=3
  - wcwidth=0.1.7=py36h3d5aa90_0
  - webencodings=0.5.1=py36_1
  - werkzeug=0.14.1=py36_0
  - wheel=0.31.1=py36_0
  - widgetsnbextension=3.4.1=py36_0
  - wincertstore=0.2=py36h7fe50ca_0
  - winpty=0.4.3=4
  - yaml=0.1.7=hc54c509_2
  - zeromq=4.2.5=he025d50_1
  - zlib=1.2.11=h8395fce_2
  - zope=1.0=py36_1
  - zope.interface=4.5.0=py36hfa6e2cd_0
  - opencv-contrib=3.3.1=py36_1
prefix: C:\Users\Marcial\Anaconda3\envs\cvcourse_windows
```

The error is :

```
(base) C:\Users\Jaysurya\Desktop>conda env create -f cvcourse_windows.yml 
 Collecting package metadata: done 
Solving environment: failed  
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict: 
- numpy==1.15.1=py36ha559c80_0 
Use "conda search <package> --info" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

[anaconda promt screent shot attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q68Xt.png)

Comment: It could probably be a version error?

Comment: i tried downgrading my anaconda python to 3.6 and it still  gives me UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:                                            - keras-base==2.2.2=py36_0                                                                                              - mkl==2019.0=118

Answer (score 0):

With the following commands you can create an environment with opencv:

```
conda create -n py3_opencv python=3.6
source activate py3_opencv
pip install opencv-python==3.4
conda install ... (if you need other dependencies)
```

(You can use [conda install](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/opencv) if you like, but I personally prefer pip's opencv version)

Use

```
pip install opencv-contrib-python==3.4
```

if you need a contrib version.

Hope this helps.